# Tego un problema con mi sistema

Tags: php, java, c#, laravel, index

```
`Tengo un problema a la hora de actualizar los datos de un registro ya ingresado y 
 quiero actualizar por ejemplo el precio se actualizan todos los demás valores de la 
 tabla y los demás registros **negrita**

 //funciones.js
 `function Guardar_Cambios_Detalle_Guia(idGuia,numGuia,cantidad,peso,precioGuia){
 $.post(
baseUrl + "/Inicio/fn_actualizar_detalle_guia_por_proveedor",
{idGuia:idGuia,numGuia:numGuia, cantidad:cantidad, peso:peso, precioGuia:precioGuia},
function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data == "true") {
    ToastAlert(
      "icon-check",
      "Los cambios se guardaron correctamente",
      "success"
    );
    fechaDesdeCompra = $("#txtFechaDesdeProveedor").val();
    fechaHastaCompra = $("#txtFechaHastaProveedor").val();

    muestra_detalle_compras_proveedor(fechaDesdeCompra, fechaHastaCompra);
    swal.closeModal();
    //location.reload(); // Recargar la página después de eliminar
    return false;
  } else if (data == "false") {
    ToastAlert(
      "icon-error",
      "Error: Algo salio mal durante la operación.",
      "danger"
    );
  }
}
```

);
}
`

//main.js
`$(document).on('click','.btnEditarDetalleGuia',function (e) {
var proveedor = $("#txtProveedorDetalleGuia").text();
var fecha = $("#txtFechaDetalleGuia").text();
numGuia = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
cantidad = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
peso = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text();
precioGuia = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5)').text();
idGuia = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(8)').text();
console.log(numGuia, idGuia,cantidad, peso, precioGuia);

```
$("#editarGuiaModalLabelProveedor").attr("value", proveedor);
$("#editarDetalleGuianumeroGuia").attr("value", numGuia);
$("#editarDetalleGuiacantidad").attr("value", cantidad);
$("#editarDetalleGuiapeso").attr("value", peso);
$("#editarDetalleGuiaprecio").attr("value", precioGuia);
idGuia = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(8)').text();
$("#editarDetalleGuiaIdGuia").attr("value", idGuia);
document.querySelector('#editarGuiaModalLabelProveedor').innerHTML = proveedor;
document.querySelector('#editarGuiaModalLabelFecha').innerHTML = fecha;
$('#editarGuiaModal').modal({ show:true });
```

});`

**negrita**
`
//inicio.php
public function fn_actualizar_detalle_guia_por_proveedor(){
$idGuia = $this->request->getPost("idGuia");
$numGuia = $this->request->getPost("numGuia");
$cantidad = $this->request->getPost("cantidad");
$peso = $this->request->getPost("peso");
$precio = $this->request->getPost("precioGuia");

```
    $reportD = new Minicio();
    $respuesta = $reportD- 
 >actualizar_detalle_guia_por_proveedor($idGuia,$numGuia,$cantidad,$peso,$precio);
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}
public function fn_eliminar_detalle_guia_por_proveedor(){
    $idGuia = $this->request->getPost("idGuia");

    $reportD = new Minicio();
    $respuesta = $reportD->eliminar_detalle_guia_por_proveedor($idGuia);
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
 }
  public function fn_eliminar_precios_personal_ed(){
    $idGrupo = $this->request->getPost("idGrupo");

    $reportD = new Minicio();
    $respuesta = $reportD->eliminar_precios_personal_ed($idGrupo);
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}
  public function fn_eliminar_saldos_personal_ed(){
    $idGrupo = $this->request->getPost("idGrupo");

    $reportD = new Minicio();
    $respuesta = $reportD->eliminar_saldos_personal_ed($idGrupo);
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}




  **negrita**
   //Minicio.php

 public function 
 actualizar_detalle_guia_por_proveedor($idGuia,$numGuia,$cantidad,$peso,$precioGuia){
            $result = $this->query("UPDATE tb_guia2 SET numGuia = '".$numGuia."', 
   cantidad = '".$cantidad."', peso = '".$peso."', precioGuia = '".$precioGuia."' WHERE 
  idGuia ='".$idGuia."'");
            return $result;
    }`
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.